# Selenium WebDrive - Find element by Javascript or onclick

Tags: javascript, selenium, onclick

I am new in Selenium and I don't know if there is a way to search by javascript or  onclick method.

I have the following HTML

```
...
<td>
<input id="Disable" class="buttons" type="button" name="Disable" onclick="javascript:actionPost('Edit', '1')" value="Disable">
</td>
<td>
<input id="Edit" class="buttons" type="button" name="Edit" onclick="javascript:actionPost('Edit', 'LDAP_Test')" value="Edit">
</td>
....
```

The only difference is in the javaScript command. The first command is with parameter "1" and the second with "LDAP_Test".

How can I say to Selenium to click on the second button for example. I cannot change the HTML file. It should be used as it is.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since it has an ID, you shouldn't need to match on the `onclick` attribute.  You can do:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#Edit")).click();
```

Or if the ID is indeed dynamic, you could match on the `onclick` attribute:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[onclick*='actionPost'][onclick*='LDAP_Test']")).click();
```